# Shifted tiles in QGIS with mbtiles

Tags: qgis, mbtiles

I'm confused because of the representation of mbtiles files in QGIS. It seems that the whole grid is shifted by about 3 m to the south. [image: Fig.]

So far I can observe this behavior only in the context of QGIS and mbtiles.
Maybe somebody comes up with an idea?

For reverse engineering:
Load Geotiff in Tilemill and export as mbtiles. Load both files in QGIS.

On the search for the cause I have

- generated the mbtiles file with geoscript-groovy: same result -> Tilemill does not seem to be the cause.
- taken an other GeoTIF -> same result: shifted 3m south.
- loaded the mbtiles-file in MapProxy, published it as WMS and loaded it in QGIS -> fits perfectly: the mbtiles file itself it seems so not to be the cause.

Comment: What latitude is this? Could it be a 4326 / 3857 difference?

Comment: What is the the spatial reference of your source tiff?  Does the problem occure if you use vector data?